# TypeError: $ .find is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, cheerio

I'm extracting the data from a page, but I get this error

> TypeError: $ .find is not a function`

I already installed `cheerio`. When I put `trm = $.find(".item-row[data-item='TRM']").find(".item-value > span");` is when the error comes out, I get the data but this error comes out.

Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const https = require('https');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('express test');
});

https.get('https://widgetsdataifx.blob.core.windows.net/semana/semanaindicators', (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  resp.on('end', () => {
    var $ = cheerio.load(data);
    trm = $.find(".item-row[data-item='TRM']").find(".item-value > span");
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

Comment: @TusharWalzade that's almost certainly not the problem; the error message itself is pretty obvious: there is no `$.find()` method. Probably the OP just wants `$(".item-row[data-item='TRM']")` etc

Comment: @brk it's Cheerio, a lightweight jQuery for Node scraping applications

Comment: Maybe "data" is not a valid HTML scaffolding

Comment: @TusharWalzade this is nodeJS server code, no jquery conflicts here. CheerioJS is used to replace jquery dom selectors

Comment: @LucasSuárez would you not write `$(".item-row[data-item='TRM']")` in jQuery? The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Whoever's downvoting the **correct** answers is really confusing things.

Comment: Does it work if you use `trm = $(".item-row[data-item='TRM'] .item-value > span");`?

Comment: @SalmanA yes it does.

Comment: Yes thank you very much gentlemen. @Pointy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$.find()` function, just as there isn't one in jQuery. There is a `.find()` *method* on jQuery objects, but that's not what `$` represents.

```
trm = $(".item-row[data-item='TRM']").find(".item-value > span");
```

searches the markup loaded for "item-row" elements, and then from each of those it searches for `<span>` elements inside "item-value" elements.

As in "real" jQuery, the `$` object is a *function*. You make functions calls to it and pass in selectors that you want Cheerio to find in the HTML markup you've loaded.

*edit* — here is a working test. If you `npm install cheerio` you can try it yourself with Node:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

var $ = cheerio.load(`<body>
  <div class=item-row data-item=TRM>
    <div class=item-value>
      <span>THIS IS THE CONTENT</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>`);


var span = $(".item-row[data-item='TRM']").find(".item-value > span");
console.log(span.text());
```

Comment: a .find() method exists: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#findselector and https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini yes, it does, and as you can plainly see *it's called in the code I posted*.  As with "real" jQuery, however, it's not a method on the `$` object, is a method on objects *returned* by jQuery calls.

Comment: This is the same, first you must load data in cheerio, then find() method is available on generated object

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini No, that is not correct. The `$` represents the *function* you call to search through the DOM that you load with `.load()`.  Would you look through the DOM in  a web page by calling `$.find()`? Also, how would you explain the error that clearly says that `$.find is not a function`?

Comment: It would have taken you vastly less time to simply try out some sample code in Node than making this incorrect argument. From the Cheerio documentation: *First you need to load in the HTML. This step in jQuery is implicit, since jQuery operates on the one, baked-in DOM. With Cheerio, we need to pass in the HTML document.*  That step, calling `.load(htmlSource)`, returns the function that you can subsequently use to search through the loaded HTML over and over again for any selectors you want.

Comment: In jQuery [utility functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/) can be called directly. Looking at the cheerio docs I only see two utility functions and `.find` is not one of them.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini answer updated with a working example.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini right. It's kind-of a neat library, quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Playing with the code it looks like the `var $ = cheerio.load( data )` expression assigns the `$` variable to an instance of cheerio with the HTML document loaded.  You then can traverse the dom like you would with jQuery.

Changing line 20 to

```
$("body").find(".item-row[data-item='TRM']").find(".item-value > span");
```

Will work because we are selecting the `body` and then calling the `find` method on the return value of the original query instead of the instance of cheerio itself.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Or simply `$(".item-row[data-item='TRM']")`, just as one would in jQuery on a web page.

Comment: You mean `$(".item-row[data-item='TRM']")`? ;)

Comment: Sorry yes; typo fixed.