# array.find(name) returns TypeError name is not a function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, find

I've looked as similar questions online but couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

- [Similar question but with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142737/typeerror-find-is-not-a-function)
- [Similar question but with MongoDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56181055/model-find-is-not-a-function)
- [Similar error but doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63709751/error-users-find-is-not-a-function-but-acttualy-it-is)
- [Similar question but doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68120828/find-is-not-a-function-nodejs)

**Problem**

I have the following 2 constants:

```
const short_names = { aa: 'AppleAid', bb: 'BananaBoat', cc: 'CloudCut'};
const long_names = ['AppleAid', 'BananaBoat', 'CloudCut'];
```

And the following custom function `find_name(name)`

```
function find_name(name) {
    if (name.length === 2) return (short_names[name] || 'na');
    else return (long_names.find(name) || 'na');
}
```

When running

```
console.log(find_name('BananaBoat'))
```

Locally and in an online compiler, I find the same `TypeError`:

```
node /tmp/o2G8YS3Ds1.js
/tmp/o2G8YS3Ds1.js:6
    else return (long_names.find(name) || 'na');
                            ^

TypeError: BananaBoat is not a function
    at Array.find (<anonymous>)
    at find_name (/tmp/o2G8YS3Ds1.js:6:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/o2G8YS3Ds1.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

**Failed Attempts**

- I tried changing my *print* statement to this:

  ```
  console.log(find_name('BananaBoat')[0])
  ```
- I also tried changing my function to use the ternary notation:

  ```
  function find_name(name) {
      return (name.length === 2) ? (short_names[name] || 'na') : (long_names.find(name) || 'na');
  }
  ```
- I've tried implementing this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788536/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-find-in-ie/52412322#52412322) with using `filter`:

  ```
  function find_name(name) {
       if (name.length === 2) return (short_names[name] || 'na');
       else return (long_names.filter(function (x) {
            return x === e
       })[0]|| 'na');
  }
  ```

  But then I get a `e is not defined` error.

**Edit**

The goal is to have the function return the name of the matched element if there is one and if not then just `na`.

I'm sure this is a straightforward solution to some simple mistake I've made, but because I'm not an expert in Javascript I'm unable to find the solution.

Comment: the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) array method takes a function that is used to test each item. So you will get this error when you provide it with a string. I guess you probably meant `.find(elem => elem === name)`, but that doesn't make much sense either because when `name` is in the array, that will just return the same `name` you started with. So I can't put this into an answer.

Comment: [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) takes a _callback_, the predicate, not just a value. In your last attempt what value _were_ you expecting e to have? Did you mean name?

Comment: Yes so the goal is to have the function return the name that I passed as input

Comment: I don't agree with the vote to close: This is reproducible (I just reproduced it) and seems caused by a misunderstanding of `find`, not a typo.

Comment: `Yes so the goal is to have the function return the name that I passed as input`. Well then you can just do `function(name) {return name;}` - but you don't need a function for that!

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say ```to return the name passed as input if it exists in the `long_names` array```, I made a mistake. @RobinZigmond, I've updated my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) takes a function as its argument—not a string. If you wanted to use it here, you'd need to supply a function, such as `(s) => s === 'BananaBoat'`, as the argument. The function you provide should return `true` when it encounters the element you're looking for:

```
function find_name(name) {
    if (name.length === 2) return (short_names[name] || 'na');
    else return (long_names.find((s) => s === 'BananaBoat') !== -1 || 'na');
}
```

Instead, I would suggest using `indexOf`. It returns the first index of the string you pass in, or `-1` if the element isn't found:

```
function find_name(name) {
    if (name.length === 2) return (short_names[name] || 'na');
    else return (long_names.indexOf(name) !== -1 && name || 'na');
}
```

You could also consider this, which might be a bit clearer:

```
function find_name(name) {
    if (name.length === 2) return (short_names[name] || 'na');
    if (long_names.indexOf(name) !== -1) return name;
    return 'na';
}
```

Comment: This looks, great thank you. However is there a one liner (that uses `indexOf`) that allows the return to be the matched String in the array instead of the index @Cam?

Comment: @Liam I've added a couple ways that you can return the string.

Comment: note: `long_names.indexOf(name) !== -1` is much easier to express in modern Javascript as `long_names.includes(name)`